# Flutter - Font Awesome Icon overflow with Text

Tags: flutter, dart, icons, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm using [FontAwesomeIcon Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter) in my application.

Some Icons from FontAwesomeIcon plugin are overlap with Text widget like below Image.

[image]

I can solve this problem by adding some width between Text and Icon, but that is not good. so how to solve this problem.

I need like this Image.

[image]

here i'm not adding any width between icon and text.

Code:

```
Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.trip_origin,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'TP-23',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.idCard,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'TP-23',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Bro can you pls add code ?

Comment: @AR code added brother.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking like this ?

```
Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.trip_origin,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    SizeBox(width:10) //as per your requirement
                    Text(
                      'TP-23',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.idCard,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    SizeBox(width:10) //as per your requirement
                    Text(
                      'TP-23',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: i already tried like this brother, while trying like this space between first icon and first text is large than space between second icon and second text.

Comment: @MSARKrish use padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 10.0),  in your second child of Row

Comment: i already mentioned in my question, i know i can solve this problem adding some padding for that. but i want to know is there any other solution is there for this. because while enabling flutter inspector the fontawesome icon taking more space than given default icon space. that's why it's showing like this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the Padding widget (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html) like this

ADD PADDING TO THE LEFT AND RIGHT TO THE ICON WIDGET

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0)
      child: Icon(
        Icons.trip_origin,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      'TP-23',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    )
  ]
)
```

ADD PADDING ONLY TO THE RIGHT TO THE ICON WIDGET

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0)
      child: Icon(
        Icons.trip_origin,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      'TP-23',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    )
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    child: Container(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 500.0,
                    width: 500.0,
                    // alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                    child: Stack(
                      //alignment:new Alignment(x, y)
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.trip_origin,
                          size: 40.0,
                          color: Colors.orange,
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          top: 15.00,
                          left: 40.0,
                          child: Text(
                            'TP-23',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61045489/7857364) answer, you need to wrap your `FontAwesomeIcon` into an `FaIcon` rather than a simple `Icon`.

Your snippet would be:

```
FaIcon(
  FontAwesomeIcons.idCard,
  color: Colors.white,
)
```