# Fontawesome icon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

why my icon in CircleAvatar is not in centre?

[image]

```
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        IconButton(
                          icon: CircleAvatar(
                            child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.tshirt, color: Colors.white,),
                            radius: 60.0,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan
                          ),
                          iconSize: 50.0,
                          onPressed: () {
                            //
                          },
                        ),
                        Text('Odzież')
                      ],
                    ),
```

I use fontawesome to add icon, but after adding icon, he is not in thecentre of the circle avatar, have anybody any solutions to this problem?

Comment: this keeps happening I dont think its from the icon though, its from the iconButton replace is with gesture detector with the child as the icon and onpressed to on tap you will see its centered.

Comment: I try and it not help me :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is very common issue with this library.

You have to use **FaIcon** widget which come with the package. They also mention this issue in their [documentations FAQ](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter).

Solution :

> Just Replace your icon widget with FaIcon.

```
CircleAvatar(
   child: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.tshirt, color: Colors.white,), // Icon widget changed with FaIcon
        radius: 60.0,
         backgroundColor: Colors.cyan
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
                    IconButton(
                          icon: CircleAvatar(
                            child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.tshirt, color: Colors.white,),
                            radius: 60.0,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan
                          ),
                          iconSize: 50.0,
                          onPressed: () {
                            //
                          },
                        ),
```

with

```
                  GestureDetector(
                          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.tshirt, color: Colors.white,),
                            radius: 60.0,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan
                          ),
                          iconSize: 50.0,
                          onTap: () {
                            //
                          },
                        ),
```

This might help as a workaround .